# JSON Deserialized Untyped errors when one character longer

Tags: apex, json

Given the following:

```
String a = '{"field":13316956360165196849}';
Map<String, Object> tokenObject = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(a);
```

I get the error:

> System.JSONException: For input string: "13316956360165196849" at [line:1, column:2]

However if I remove the last digit it deserializes fine

```
String a = '{"field":1331695636016519684}';
Map<String, Object> tokenObject = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(a);
```

Any idea why having one character longer causes JSON to choke? Right now I do not have a work around and looking to get more info on what may be the cause

Comment: 32-bit integer limit, perhaps?

Comment: @DerekF Yea I was thinking that and if that is the case the only way around it will be to use regex to remove that field/value from the JSON. Im checking now to see if it is critical the value be present downstream....I have no control over the type so cannot get it change to a string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My comment was close, this is an issue because the integer literal `13316956360165196849` overflows the 64-bit long

Max value for a long:
9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (10^18)

Your value:
13,316,956,360,165,196,849 (10^19)

Comment: but the error `For input string: "13316956360165196849"` makes me think it was trying to deserialize it into a string due to the error? Or maybe just a bad message

Comment: So basically the only way around is to remove it from the JSON string? A class to deserialize into is a worse option as a lot of the field names have `.` in them so I would still have to do a lot of manipulation or yuk write a parser.

Comment: It'd be hard to represent a number too large for the platform to handle as anything other than a string in an error message though, and a value in JSON that isn't quoted and isn't true/false must be a number, yeah?

Comment: Makes sense. Removal it is

Comment: Is there possibly a way to do a partial typed deserialization? Something that says "treat this one field as a string, and then deserialize everything else as a Map<String, Object>"?

Comment: Thats a thought if it becomes a larger issue. For now it is pretty easy to remove or put " " around the number using `string.replace( regex ,....)`